# Broken animation with NavigationLink and ObservableObject

Tags: swift, swiftui, swiftui-navigationlink

I have a SwiftUI parent view that pushes a detail view on a navigation stack. The detail view has a binding to some data on the parent view.

Depending on the setup some animation that occurs upon change of the data is broken on the detail view. A broken animation in SwiftUI is not only ugly but may point to a deeper issue that may cause rendering performance (see https://developer.apple.com/wwdc21/10022).

Specifically, the issue only occurs when:

- I pass a binding to some data on an `ObservableObject`; *and*
- the detail view is pushed onto a `NavigationStack.`

It works as expected for all other cases.

I found one workaround by passing the `ObservableObject` down to the child view instead of a binding to the data property. However I don't consider this a viable solution because it is an architectural compromise by exposing unneeded information to the detail view (among other reasons).

Here is a minimal reproducible example.
[image: screenshot]

```
import SwiftUI

struct SpaceProbe {
    // let id: UUID = UUID() // does not help
    let name: String
    var launched: Bool = false
}

class SpacePort: ObservableObject {
    @Published var probe: SpaceProbe = SpaceProbe(name: "Psyche", launched: true)
}

struct ContentView: View {
    @StateObject var spacePort: SpacePort = SpacePort()
    @State var probe: SpaceProbe = SpaceProbe(name: "Psyche", launched: true)
    var body: some View {
        NavigationStack {
            List {
                Section(header: Text("State:")) {
                    NavigationLink {
                        Cell(probe: $probe)
                            .padding()
                    } label: {
                        Text("Details (works)")
                    }
                    Cell(probe: $probe)
                }
                Section(header: Text("State Object:")) {
                    NavigationLink {
                        Cell(probe: $spacePort.probe)
                            .padding()
                    } label: {
                        Text("Details (broken animation)")
                    }
                    NavigationLink {
                        ObjectCell(spacePort: spacePort)
                            .padding()
                    } label: {
                        Text("Details (works but bad architecture)")
                    }
                    Cell(probe: $spacePort.probe)
                }

            }
            .navigationBarTitle("Space Probe")
        }
    }
}

struct Cell: View {
    @Binding var probe: SpaceProbe
    var body: some View {
        VStack(alignment: probe.launched ? .trailing : .leading) {
            HStack {
                Text(probe.name)
                Spacer()
                Button(probe.launched ? "Cancel" : "Launch") {
                    Task { @MainActor in
                        withAnimation {
                            probe.launched.toggle()
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            Text("️").font(.system(size: 40))
                .padding()
        }
    }
}

struct ObjectCell: View {
    @ObservedObject var spacePort: SpacePort
    var body: some View {
        VStack(alignment: spacePort.probe.launched ? .trailing : .leading) {
            HStack {
                Text(spacePort.probe.name)
                Spacer()
                Button(spacePort.probe.launched ? "Cancel" : "Launch") {
                    Task { @MainActor in
                        withAnimation {
                            spacePort.probe.launched.toggle()
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            Text("️").font(.system(size: 40))
                .padding()
        }
    }
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}
```

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know why the problem is being seen, but there is an easy workaround.

Add `.animation` to the `VStack` in `Cell`:

```swift
struct Cell: View {
    @Binding var probe: SpaceProbe
    var body: some View {
        VStack(alignment: probe.launched ? .trailing : .leading) {
            // content as before
        }
        .animation(.easeInOut, value: probe.launched) // <- ADDED
    }
}
```

Comment: Indeed, this fixes the issue. Unclear why the implicit animation works when the explicit one doesn't. At least this shows, that there is no superfluous rendering happening.